# Spring how to handle file saving

Tags: java, spring, transactions

In application I am currently saving file to file system and then updating database. My question is: should I do it in transaction or before transaction?

Currently I am doing it like this - before transaction and if failure in saving file appears, it does not update database:

```
@POST
@Path("passport")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response saveDocument(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                                   @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
                                   @FormDataParam("documentTypeId") int documentTypeId,
                                   @FormDataParam("id") int id) {

    String fileName = fileDetail.getFileName();
    String result = "";
    String[] split = fileName.split("\\.");
    if (split.length == 1) {
        //No extension
        result = split[0] + new Date().getTime();
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length - 1; i++) {
            result += split[i];
        }
        result += new Date().getTime() + "." + split[split.length - 1];
    }
    try {
        fileService.saveFile(result, uploadedInputStream);
        persistenceService.saveDocument(fileName, id, documentTypeId);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "File saving failed", e);
       //TODO Throw exception
    }

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

If I save it this way, I have no way to ensure that if exception occurs during transaction, file is not saved. The logical way is to do saving after updating database in transaction so that if exception happens, transaction is rolling back. But I am not sure if it is good practice to do I/O actions in transaction.

Answer (score 0):

This is not straightforward! The reason is, its very difficult to do a full rollback system at a "library" level that is generic enough to work across all file systems. You may think it is easy, but it is not, and requires both OS and filesystem support.

Take the following for example, if you were to write to a new file, rollback is simply removing the file. IF you were to delete a file, rollback is undeleting it (need OS support). Finally if you were to modify a file, you would need ot return to the state before the transaction (requiring access to the journaling on some file systems).

Now to be absolutely atomic, the Java library would need to directly work with the journalistic system, so that even if the JVM were to crash mid transaction, the JFS will rollback the file changes.

Consider instead of saving to files, using a filesystem layer, or even a NoSQL database of some sort?

Comment: Well, I assume that transaction is indeed atomic and if any exception is thrown from within, it causes rollback. So what I think, I could update database first and save file afterwards. If saving file throws exception, I could rethrow it and transaction would fail, causing it to roll back. But I am not sure if I/O operations should be done in transactions.

Comment: That is the thing, at the moment FileIO is only atomic on some file systems. Have a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html#atomic

Comment: Yes, but if I use it in transaction, I do not care how atomic it is. I only care that transaction is atomic.

Comment: And that is actually the problem. What happens if the JVM crashes? Or if the os crashes or has a power failure? For there to be a standard library for transactions to apply to file io it needs to follow the same rules as dB transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with transactional operations over filesystem using [XADisk](https://xadisk.java.net/)